# Fantasy book about a school boy after WWI who is transported to a Tolkien-esque fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, books

It was set right after WWI I believe because they mentioned the Great War. It was set in England at first following an academy school boy who by some manner is transported to a Tolkienesque fantasy land and he's some sort of chosen one. I remember an old wise wizard and giant eagles they flew on. I read it in the 2010's but it was a far older book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the names of any characters or places they visited?  Do you remember the cover art?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this was when I was in maybe 3rd grade, definitely early 2010's

Comment: With England and the war it sounds like Narnia, but I can not remember eagles, only horses

Comment: They were definitely a big part, I remember that at least one of them spoke

Comment: Could it be Maurice Gee's *Halfmen of O* series - not quite right, set in NZ and the main character is a girl (Susan) and her cousin Nick - transported to "O" where they fight the "halfmen", including travel with some eagle-like bird people and meet wise forest dwellers who are healers.